# How to check the availability of a resource using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

If I have a URL to a video file, how can I detect if the resource pointed by the URL is valid and exists before it can be displayed? I've seen some answers suggesting AJAX, but I only know AJAX to send and retrieve some data, not to get the status of the file whether it exists or not.

For example, if I have a URL like `http://www.example.com/video.mp4`, how could I check whether `video.mp4` exists or not and can or cannot be retrieved?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't really need ajax, just create a video element, and see if it can load the source

```
var video = document.createElement('video');

video.onload = function() {
    alert('success, it exist');
    // show video element
}

video.onerror = function() {
    alert('error, couldn\'t load');
    // don't show video element
}

video.src = 'http://www.example.com/video.mp4';
```

Different browsers play different formats, to check if the file can be played in the current browser, you can use the `canplaythrough` event

```
video.oncanplaythrough = function() {
    alert("This file can be played in the current browser");
};
```

if the file is on the same domain, and ports and protocol match, you can use ajax to do a HEAD request and see if the resource exists, but that won't work cross-domain

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open('HEAD', '/folder/video.mp4');

http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == this.DONE) {
        if (this.status != 404) {
          // resource exists
        }
    }
};

http.send();
```

Comment: That's fot HTML5 only, though.

Comment: @g.tsh - how else would you play a video? There's Flash, but then you'd need a dedicated player

Comment: That's actually what I needed! I just need to ask one more thing: after I create the video element, how do I insert the video element in the place I want in the document? I never used HTML5 video before, and I remember reading that to use HTML5 video can use just simple HTML and not involving javascript. so I don't know how javascript can add and play HTML5 video element in the specific location in the document. Thanks! (Oh and the video is in different domain, so I guess I can't use the AJAX then..)

Answer (score 3):

You can send a `HEAD` request. `HEAD` requests send back only the HTTP headers, so if you get a status of 200 or 304 it means the resource exists, if you get a 404 it means the resource doesn't exist.