# Does HTML5 Video.src API has a timeout

Tags: html, html5-video

I wonder if HTML5 Video API has a timeout setting somewhere when loading the source?

What I want to do:

```
var videocontainer = document.getElementbyID('somevidcontainer')
videocontainer.src = "http://someurlwhichisnotavail.com/test.mp4" // invalid url
```

Now I want to set the timeout in case it takes too long...

Is there a timeout setting somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not specifically seeing a time out attribute, however I found two useful links that may help, either checking readystate or listening for error event. Links are below: 
http://jsfiddle.net/26tzkvy5/ (code below from fiddle link I found),

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
<video autoplay="false" controls width="400">
    <source src="https://someFalseurl.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<script>
    document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].addEventListener('play', function(){
        alert("play");
    });
    document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].addEventListener('error', function(){
        alert("error");
    });
    document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].src='https://someFalseurl.mp4';
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Lastly, another Stack Overflow thread showing various ways to check for an invalid resource:
 [How to check the availability of a resource using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28262008/check-the-availability-of-a-resource-using-javascript) , hope this information helps.